# passing parameter values from parent and child forms c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have two forms, one with a button 'Add' which loads the second form with two textboxes and a submit button.

First of all I need a way of passing the text box values to form 1 (parent) and making form 2 close on the submit..

How can I do this? Until now I have written this code but it is not working

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            emailForm EmailF = new emailForm();
            if ((EmailF.Username != null &&  EmailF.Password != null)) 
            {
                string user = EmailF.Username;
                string pass = EmailF.Password;

            }
```

and in the emailForm.cs

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = username_textbox.Text;
            password = username_textbox.Text;
            Close();

        }

        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { this.username = value; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return password;}
            set { this.password = value; }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying "not working" ? The property you read, for example, EmailF.Username is empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at [`Form.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx). This will do what you want, and when the user closes the dialog window you can make sure they clicked "OK" (or whatever else) and then grab the values from the form.

Comment: but when I click on submit, the form does not even close. how come?

Comment: Er... you should use `Close()`, don't just make it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```